# chrome devtools network tab not showing data about websockets

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, devtools

Not sure why is this happening, as it worked before. Maybe it is because of update, or I clicked something accidentally.

When I go to network tab of chrome devtools, and try to inspect some websocket, I get this grey area.

My chrome version details:

```
Google Chrome   101.0.4951.54 (OfficialBuild) (x86_64) 
Revision    67da1aeb32cedd27634ca6634fb79cbd85d3f0ab-refs/branch-heads/4951@{#1126}
OS  macOS Version 12.2.1 (Build 21D62) JavaScript   V8 10.1.124.11 User
agent   Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7)
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54
Safari/537.36
```

[image: chrome devtools]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I fixed it for me (probably not the best solution):

I just needed to go to devtools settings and “Restore deaults and reload”.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).